# Generic collection collision

Tags: c#, generics, covariance

Here's my best attempt to recreate the situation.

```
public interface IFoo
{

}

public class Foo : IFoo { }

public class Bar : IFoo { }

public class CollectionOf<T> : List<IFoo>
{

}

public class Bars : CollectionOf<Bar>
{

}

public class Test
{
    public void Test()
    {
        CollectionOf<IFoo> bars = new Bars();
    }
}
```

Compiler complains on the instantiation. Bars is a collection of IFoos. Is this one of those covariance/contravariance issues?

Comment: Thanks @EdS. What is the fix?

Comment: If you want support for covariance/contravariance, we will need to know whether `CollectionOf` is for reading from the collection or adding to the collection? It cannot be both and still support covariance or contravariance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fix, if there is one would depend on what it is that's not working for you.  I can get your example to compile in two ways, either use IEnumerable or define your CollectionOf as an interface with the out generic modifier.  Whether either is a fix for you I don't know:

```
public interface IFoo { }

public class Foo : IFoo { }

public class Bar : IFoo { }

public interface CollectionOf<out T> : IEnumerable<IFoo> { }

public class Bars : CollectionOf<Bar> { }

public class Test
{
    public void Test()
    {
        IEnumerable<IFoo> bars1 = new Bars();
        CollectionOf<IFoo> bars2 = new Bars();
    }
}
```

Comment: I believe this is what I'm looking for. I need to remove from CollectionOf, so the out is what I needed.

Answer (score 4):

Yes.

Think about it for a second; `bars` should legally be able to hold objects of any type that implement `IFoo`.  However, an object of type `Bars` can *only* hold objects of type `Bar`.

Using your code this would be allowed, which is obviously wrong.

```
CollectionOf<IFoo> bars = new Bars();
bars.Add( new Foo() );  // Uh oh!
```

That would effectively break the type safety afforded to you via generics.

Comment: What if I promise to only put bars in that collection? Isn't that what the <in T> or <out T> are all about?

Comment: If you only want to put `Bar` in the collection, why not just use `CollectionOf<Bar> bars = new Bars();`?

Comment: @Matthew: No, they don't allow for incorrect behavior.  You'll never be able to add a `Foo` to a collection of `Bar` unless you work solely via the interface.  This isn't C++; generics are strongly typed.  The situation that would ensure form your example would cause behavior that makes no sense and is not defined in the standard.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is.

If this was allowed, you would be able to place any object into that collection, as long as it implemented the `IFoo` interface, but that wouldn't be safe for the collection.

Let me illustrate:

```
var b = new Bars();
CollectionOf<IFoo> bars = b;
bars.Add(Dummy); // implements IFoo, but does not descend from Bar
```

At this point, what does `b` contain? An object of type `Dummy`? That would be bad, and thus this is not allowed in the first place.

Comment: Thank you, yes that makes perfect since. Where does <out T> come in to play?

Comment: `<out T>` or _covariance_ means that a class `Foo<out T>` can have its elements upcasted. For example, `Foo<object> myFoo = new Foo<string>();`. In this situation, `T` can only be used on return types (hence the out). For more information check out this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee207183.aspx)